# Having trouble saving dynamically generated inputs in a filament form

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-filament

I have been trying to figure out this problem for a few weeks now, trying various forums, the docs, and AI tools that are outdated.

I want to create a series of select options (or radios/ checkboxes) that utilize my tags table to generate the choices. In this case it is hobbyRatings (tag type = 13-- polymorphic M:M relationship).

This code below gets the individual ratings to display with their respective choices, but the choices are not saving, and I am not familiar enough with how filament code works to know how to make it save, when everything else saves by default.

See sample DB and expected rendering : [Sample](https://imgur.com/a/WDe6Z19)

The morph examples in the docs dont seem to align with this goal in mind.  Adding the 'hobbyRating' in a
->relationship()  doesnt support morphToMany, or if added within the loop, simply displays all rating parents and child options.   I only need to save the chosen id's in each select box. I do not need to save the parent ID

So again, the below code renders as expected but I'm not sure how to save it from there.
Hope you can provide some guidance.

Also, how do i see what data is being sent for troubleshooting? if i add dd($data) or dd($data['hobbyRatings']);   or really dd anything, nothing displays. I am not sure how  to troubleshoot this or figure out what data is being passed without dd, and debugbar doesnt provide any data either.  I am doing everything I know how to do, but the standard troubleshooting steps aren't working within filament v3.   I think the whole "schema() " thing is throwing me off

Code:
Hobby Model:

```
public function hobbyRatings(): MorphToMany
{
    return $this->morphToMany(Tag::class, 'taggable')->where('tag_type', 13)
                ->withTimestamps();
}
```

HOBBYRESOURCE

```
 public static function form(Form $form): Form
    {
        return $form
            ->schema([
//Other form fields to hobby-

//Ratings is a polymorphic relationship
        Section::make('Ratings')
                       ->schema(function (Hobby $record) {
                           $components   = [];
                           $allRatings   = Tag::type(13)->get();
                           $modelRatings = $record->hobbyRatings;

                           foreach (
                               $allRatings->where('parent_id', null) as $rating
                           ) {
                               $component = Select::make('hobbyRatings.'
                                                         .$rating->id)
                                                  ->label($rating->tag)
                                                  ->options($allRatings->where('parent_id',
                                                      $rating->id)->pluck('tag',
                                                      'id'));

                               if ($modelRatings->contains('id', $rating->id)) {
                                   $component->default($modelRatings->where('parent_id',
                                       $rating->id)->first()->id);
                               }

                               $components[] = $component;
                           }

                           return $components;
                       })
                       ->columnSpanFull(),

            ]);

    }

  protected static function saveRelationships($record, $data): void
    {

        if (isset($data['hobbyRatings'])) {
            $tagIds = [];
            foreach ($data['hobbyRatings'] as $parentId => $childId) {
                if ($childId) {
                    $tagIds[] = $childId;
                }
            }

            dd($tagIds);
            $record->hobbyRatings()->sync($tagIds);
            $record->save();
        }

        parent::saveRelationships($record, $data);
    }

}
```

In the non filament attempt at this project, this worked, but I am having difficulty altering it for filamaent / livewire :

```
 @foreach($ratings->whereNull('parent_id') as $rating)
        <div class=" col-12">
            <div class="mb-3">
                <div class="form-row  align-items-center">
                    <div class="col-sm-5">
                        <label class="control-label control-label-left "
                               for="{{$rating->slug}}">{{$rating->tag}}</label></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-7">
                        <select name="ratings[]" id="{{$rating->slug}}"
                                class="form-control" data-bs-role="select" wire:model="rating.{{$rating->slug}}">
                            <option>Select</option>
                            @foreach($ratings->where('parent_id', $rating->id) as $option )
                                <option description="{{ $option->description }}" value="{{ $option->id }}"
                                        data-parent-id="{{ $option->parent_id }} ">
                                    {{ $option->tag }}
                                </option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <small id="{{$rating->slug}}_Help" class="form-text text-muted ">
                    {{ $rating->description }}
                </small>
            </div>
        </div>

        {{$description}}
```

Controller

```
public function update (UpdateHobbyRequest $request, Hobby $hobby)
    {
        
        $hobby->update($request->all());
...
        
        $this->syncTags($request, $hobby);
     
       

        return back()->with('success', 'Hobby Updated');
    }
 protected function syncTags ($request, Hobby $hobby): void
    {
        $categories = $request->input('categories.*');
        $ratings    = $request->input('ratings.*');
        $ratings    = array_filter($ratings, function ($a) {
            return trim($a) !== '';
        });

        $array = array_merge($categories, $ratings);

        $hobby->tags()->sync($array);
    }
```